# Why can't I run X-Ray daemon inside docker container in AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-xray

I read the AWS X-RAY and AWS Elastic Beanstalk documentation and wonder the question why do they say that X-RAY daemon should be run as extension. As I know Elastic Beanstalk can run my application as docker container. Can I just run the daemon inside that container?

Documentation:

Here they say that we should run the X-RAY daemon as extension:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-daemon-beanstalk.html

Here they show how to run that daemon inside Docker:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-daemon-local.html

Answer (score 0):

You should edit your dockerFile to have the X-ray Daemon

```
FROM amazonlinux
RUN yum install -y unzip
RUN curl -o daemon.zip https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/aws-xray-assets.us-east-2/xray-daemon/aws-xray-daemon-linux-3.x.zip
RUN unzip daemon.zip && cp xray /usr/bin/xray
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/xray", "-t", "0.0.0.0:2000", "-b", "0.0.0.0:2000"]
EXPOSE 2000/udp
EXPOSE 2000/tcp
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I thought. I understand that I have to add those lines to Dockerfile to  run the daemon. I just preparing to the exam and found a few example questions, where author said that only the option with Elastic Beanstalk extension is right and all others are not. That is why I wondered if the author is right.

Comment: I'm not sure how specifically it is setup in eb. In docker you can do like this for sure.